# how to open a modal from a link that might be amended

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a login modal. it is working somewhat.  the problem is when server adds ceid 
to create a link like http://localhost/m/login.php?ceid=69cf016835e8e63439f905a5c5e6a0f6

```
$('a[href^=\"login.php\"]').on( \"click\", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#Modal').modal('show');
});
```

but it dose not work.

if I use this it works when the cid is gone`

```
    $('a[href$=\"login.php\"]').on( \"click\", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  $('#Modal').modal('show');
 });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ^ which means ”starts with”. You would need to swap it for * to be a ”contains”.

`a[href*=\"login.php\"]`

Although can you not add a id or a class?

Comment: Sorry I meant * not ~ I will amend

Comment: Please try `a[href*=\"login.php\"]`